# npm install failling at node-gyp rebuild and libpq

Tags: linux, fedora, postgresql, node.js

```
> libpq@1.8.9 install /home/johnsoct/bobtail/node_modules/libpq
> node-gyp rebuild

/home/johnsoct/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.4/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin/node-gyp: line 5: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js: No such file or directory
```

I have read the error, and no, there isn't anything installed at /usr/local/lib/... When I install node-gyp globally, it doesn't install there.

I've tried:

- reinstalling postgres (https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PostgreSQL)
- installing libpq for fedora
- restarting 512394823094 times
- removing node_modules and reinstalling (over and over just hoping something magical happens)
- removing package-lock.json and re-installing
- some other stuff I've long forgotten

One little hint I'm aware of: the package that ISN'T getting installed on `npm install` is `pg-native`. Not sure that makes a difference, but figure it's related since `libpq` is being mentioned in the install report.

If you're curious, this is what my PATH looks like (I installed and uninstalled postgres using linuxbrew originally):
`/home/johnsoct/bin:/usr/pgsql-10/bin:/usr/pgsql-10/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/postgresql@10/bin:/home/johnsoct/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/postgresql@10/bin:/home/johnsoct/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.4/bin:/home/johnsoct/.local/bin:/home/johnsoct/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin`

Any advice/suggestions would be really helpful... Losing my mind here.

Answer (score 1):

This is very far fetched, but since I had the same issues building just libpq using node-gyp I thought I'd share my fix anyways, just in case.

My error output looked like this:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ekik/Source/home/grafana/node_modules/libpq
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'object-assign'
npm ERR! Require stack:
```

It started happening when I upgraded from NodeJS 14 to 16 or 18 on Manjaro Linux. Apparently the node-gyp package that's being shipped is using tons of deprecated stuff (gathered from the npm install logs), that apparently isn't installed by default (anymore).

My very dirty fix was simply:

```
sudo npm install --global object-assign code-point-at number-is-nan request
```

Please be aware that this pollutes your global node_modules.